# In a Bash script, how to use a variable to set multiple command options?

Tags: bash, shell, string-interpolation

I want to store options to arbitrary commands as strings in bash so that I can do e.g.

```
presets_A='-A'
presets_B='-A -l -F'
ls $presets_A
ls $presets_B
```

The first one works, the socond gives `ls: invalid option -- ' '`.

The same happens when I try to store the entire command in a string variable (as opposed to a function
or an alias, which is not what I want):

```
presets_A='ls -A'
presets_B='ls -A -l -F'
$presets_A
$presets_B
```

This gives `ls -A: command not found`. Not good. Obviously, I haven't yet found the correct arbitrary 
mixture of `$%"(@]}"` quotes and parens that Bash is so famous for. `${!presets_A}` also didn't work
but chances are I got confused and messed up.

**EDIT** for clarification, I do know how to use a function to encapsulate setting options and subsuming a bunch of parametrized calls under a single command. What I'm looking for is the equivalent of (Bash) `foo "$@"` or (Python) `foo( *P, **Q )` or JS `foo( ...P )` such that I get a single serializable and transportable value that comprises the arguments to a call in a single place.

Comment: Obligatory link http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050 - and it's not an arbitrary mixture of those symbols that you're looking for.

Comment: I'm unable to reproduce this with your code as posted. Are you sure you're not quoting the variables? Have you modified `IFS`?

Comment: @TomFenech I know but it occasionally does feel that way

Comment: as @thatotherguy said, there's nothing actually wrong with `presets_B='-A -l -F'` followed by `ls $presets_B` - could you expand on your question so that we can reproduce your issue?

Comment: Why don't you just use an alias like `alias lB="ls -A -l -F"`

Comment: @userunknown because what I'm looking for is not a *short* way of calling a command but a *storable*, *transportable* way to capture preset arguments.

Answer (score 3):

If functions really don't do what you want, then you can use an array to separate the arguments:

```
presets_A=( -A )
presets_B=( "${presets_A[@]}" -l -F ) # or just -A -l -F

ls "${presets_A[@]}" # ls -A
ls "${presets_B[@]}" # ls -A -l -F
```

Use `"${array[@]}"` to expand the array into a list of arguments, separated by the field separator (a space, by default).

But I would consider just defining two functions

```
la () {
  ls -A
}

lalf () {
  ls -A -l -F
}
```

Comment: Worked like a charm for my script to preload common database options, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I've since found the source for my troubles; I had tried to use a variable for options in a script with this header:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
set -euo pipefail; IFS=$'\n\t'

presets_A='-A'
presets_B='-A -l -F'
ls $presets_A
ls $presets_B
```

It does work as intended when I remove the Internal Field Separator setting, and I therefore think the correct answer to my question is:

"Storing multiple command arguments in a variable is OK in Bash and should work as long as `IFS` has not been reset to something other than a space."

I can affirm that

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
set -euo pipefail; IFS=$' '

presets_A='-A'
presets_B='-A -l -F'
command_C='ls -A -l -F'
ls $presets_A
echo '----------------------------------'
ls $presets_B
echo '----------------------------------'
$command_C
```

does work as expected; thanks go to @TomFenech for pointing out that much (note the explicit `IFS=' '` near the top).

FWIW the reason i had re-set `IFS` is that there are [quite a few recommendations to do so out there](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=bash+%22set+-euo+pipefail%22+IFS&t=lm&ia=web); they call it 'Bash strict mode'. Turns out it makes your scripts incompatible in subtle ways.